# Android, managing views, task and activities

Tags: android

I need general advice.

I'm building an app that can be started via the icon (normal way) but also with an intent triggered by a click in the notification area (the app places an icon in the notification area).   The is awaken when a time event / alarm occurs.

The app has 5 to 10 views.  Is it better to open a new activity for each view?  How can I be sure not to have mutliple tasks open?  Say if my app is Activity-A, Activity-B, Activity-C and can be started from Activity-A and Activity-B (depending on if it's opened via the icon or the notification area) ... how do I clean everything upon app close?

Or is it better to have one activity and just switch views (xml layouts)?

Answer (score 0):

I'll start of with what you should watch and read. It should be clear that navigation in Android is very easy to do wrong. Google has a history of doing differently from app to app, but they are getting better. This said, if you are to do an app you should know how it is intended to work, and the best way to do that is to read the docs. As mentioned, there was an excellent [talk at IO'12](http://youtu.be/XwGHJJYBs0Q). There is also a very good section on the [design site](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html), and finally there is a good section in the [API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

To summarize: a full screen is an activity (which in turn can be constructed of fragments). The activities should in virtually all cases be structured as a tree with the root being the activity that are launched from home. For every activity you should have an "up" activity that takes you up in the hierarchy. Note that this is different from back which should take you to the last full screen state you were in. Also note that full screen means that for example tabs should not be recorded in the "back history", since they provide navigation within a screen.

When it comes to tapping a notification it should be equivalent to: pressing home, remove the task from the recents view (clearing the task), opening the task, and finally take the shortest path to get to the activity presenting the info that the notification told you about. Complicated, yes indeed... But at least there is a helper class in JB and in the support library called TaskStackBuilder.

The key to all this is a UI design that follow the Android design guidelines. Take your time to make the design for your app, and make sure to separate up (static) and back (temporal).

Answer (score 0):

It might be as simple as using a different launchmode, which you can define in the manifest or I think in the inent you are using. It takes some experimenting but SingleTask or SingleInstance may be the right choices for you,

Your activity should support onNewIntent in this case, to reuse existing Activities if that is the desired effect.

Answer (score -1):

In this case I better use one activity or use fragments.

Comment: There was an excellent talk on Google io 2012 regarding this. One activity per view is the way to go if you want to act as an android app is ment to. I will write an answer later if no one else does :-)